# Spectral data smoothing using SNV and MSC

Tags: r, filtering, smoothing

I am trying to filter the hyperspectral data. I have 204 spectral bands. I tried R for the standard normal variate (SNV) and multiple scattering correction (MSC) using the following codes.
For SNV:

```
spectra <- data[, 1:204]
means <- apply(spectra, 2, mean)
sds <- apply(spectra, 2, sd)
data_snv <- scale(spectra, center = means, scale = sds)
```

For MSC:

```
average_spectrum <- apply(spectra, 2, mean)
corrected_spectra <- sweep(spectra, 2, average_spectrum, FUN = "-")
```

Want to confirm whether these are correct or not?

Tried using these codes but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `prospectr` package to do all these like

```
library(prospectr)

snv_spc <- standardNormalVariate(X = spectra)
msc_spc <- msc(X = spectra)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But I got different values when I used the previous one and the codes suggested by you.

Comment: My point is that when you have a validated R package better to use that rather than doing it from scratch.